# self class alloc for controllers equivalent in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, subclass, base-class

I had a class UIBaseClassViewController with convenient functions in objective c.Now i'm switching to swift and i'm trying to convert it's code into swift.the function giving me problem is

```
+(UIBaseClassViewController*)getController
{
   return [[[self class] alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
}
```

i was able to convert it but it's not working fine

```
static func getController() -> Self
{
    print("sam controller class = \(String(describing:self))")
    print("SAM controller = \(self.init(nibName: String(describing:self), bundle:Bundle.main))")

    return self.init(nibName: String(describing:self), bundle:Bundle.main)
}
```

Output:

```
sam controller class = UILoginViewController
SAM controller = <Swift_And_Node.UIBaseClassViewController: 0x7f8a4ee13830>
```

created object is of type UIBaseClassViewController.it loads the nib fine but as object is of UIBaseClassViewController app crashes because it was not able to find functions in UIBaseClassViewController which are in UILoginViewController.

**How can i make it create object of child class instead of parent.UILoginViewController in this case**

for better Understanding showing adding code:

**UIBaseClassViewController**:

```
class UIBaseClassViewController: UIViewController {
static func getController() -> Self
{
    print("sam controller class = \(String(describing:self))")
    print("SAM controller = \(self.init(nibName: String(describing:self), bundle:Bundle.main))")
    var object = self
    return self.init(nibName: String(describing:self), bundle:Bundle.main)
}
}
```

**UILoginViewController**:

```
class UILoginViewController: UIBaseClassViewController {}
```

**3rd controller who need UILoginViewController**:

```
UILoginViewController.getController()
```

Comment: Small `self` refers to the object and no the class. You would need something like `String(describing: UILoginViewController.self)` to make it work.

Comment: i tried Self.init(nibName: String(describing:self), bundle:Bundle.main) which results in compile error "Use of unresolved identifier 'Self'"

Comment: I made a typo in a comment, please review.

Comment: issue is not with the nib but with object itself.i want it to be of child class instead of parent class.nib part is working fine.edited the question

Comment: You have a static func that is placed where? In a super class?

Comment: yes it's in super class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we don't need to mention nib and bundle for controller object...I moved from objective c and these things are necessary there.

**with**

```
[[UILoginViewController alloc] init]
```

**app will show black screen.**

In swift we can just use UILoginViewController() and it will automatically associate nib with the controller object.

**so to answer my question i just used**

```
self.init()
```

**instead of**

```
self.init(nibName: String(describing:self), bundle:Bundle.main)
```

Comment: Initializing from `.xib` should not differ from **Objective-C** to **Swift**. I'm actually surprised. It shouldn't work like that. You certainly are going to get a view controller by `self.init()`, but it should not be the one that is in the `.xib` file. Instead it is a totally new `UIViewController` that is not your interface builder's `UILoginViewController`.

Comment: Try putting some elements in both the `.xib` files of your `UIBaseClassViewController` & `UILoginViewController`. And then check if the corresponding view controllers are actually initialized with their elements or not.

Comment: there's no xib file for UIBaseClassViewController...i was using it just to place some common functionality... UIBaseClassViewController is inheriting uiviewcontroller and UILoginViewController is inheriting UIBaseClassViewController.this way i can use common functionality in UILoginViewController and in other controllers which are inheriting from UIBaseClassViewController

Comment: Well, fine. Still this should not load the `UILoginViewController` from your `.xib` file. Put elements in `UILoginViewController`'s `.xib` and try to initialize it using your written `static` method and then present/show that login view controller. Check if that loads successfully.

Comment: i'm not using getController function now as there's no need..just replaced self.getController() with self.init() in `UIBaseClassViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You either have to call this static function on desired view controller class or not making it static at all. Please see the example below to see how it works in Swift.

```
class ParentView: UIView {
    static func printSelf() {
        print(String(describing: self))
    }
}
class ChildView: ParentView {}

ParentView.printSelf() // Prints ParentView
ChildView.printSelf() // Prints ChildView
```

Comment: yes i'm calling it with child controller that why output was 'sam controller class = UILoginViewController'

Comment: but on self.init(nibName: String(describing:self), bundle:Bundle.main) app is creating object of UIBaseClassViewController instead of UILoginViewController

Comment: what happens when you call `UILoginViewController.getController()`

Comment: returns <Swift_And_Node.UIBaseClassViewController: 0x7f8a4ee13830>.it should be of UILoginViewController..don't know what's the issue..it's loading nib correctly in same statment

Comment: Ok, try this one. `let loginController: UILoginController = UILoginController.getController()` may be it cannot determine which class you really want without explicit type annotation here.

Comment: @SameerAzeem any luck with my previous comment?

Comment: nup same result

Comment: If your loginController is of type UILoginController it should now have all the method of UILoginController. I'm starting to think that the problem could be elsewhere.

Comment: it should but getController function is in parent class(UIBaseClassViewController) and line 'return self.init(nibName: String(describing:self), bundle:Bundle.main)'
is creating object of parent class(UIBaseClassViewController) even if i'm calling it from child class(UILoginViewController)

Comment: change `static` to `class`

Comment: `static` and `class` both associate a method with a class, rather than an instance of a class. The difference is that subclasses can override class methods; they cannot override static methods.

Comment: still no change with 'class func getController() -> Self'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179994/discussion-between-sameer-azeem-and-inokey).